# Generate a standalone figure.pdf from a figure.pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, externalize

I noticed the build of a pgf figure is a long process, and running it each time I build my document takes ages. Instead I would like to generate the figures separately.

So I wrote this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    width=12cm,
    height=2.5cm,
    scale only axis=true,
    max space between ticks=25pt,    
    every axis/.style={  
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis line style={thick,->,>=latex, shorten >=-.4cm},
    },
    xtick=\empty,
    every axis plot/.append style={thick},
    tick style={black, thick},
}

\tikzset{
    semithick/.style={line width=1.2pt},
}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate!
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\begin{document}
\input{figure.pgf}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I get a full page instead of just the figure bound to its size.

How should I generate just the figure?

Comment: Use \documentclass[tikz]{standalone} and remove the tikzexternalize stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. Using `\tikzexternalize` will generate **all** the tikz figures in your document during the first run, so new builds will run faster. (If you don't force the remake every time!)

File `main.tex` (with two figures: `width=7cm`, `height=5cm`)

Compiled with
`pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -shell-escape  main.tex`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex    

%%% File main.tex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}% to see the margins <<<<

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}% just for this plots

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
    width=7cm, % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    height=5cm, % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    scale only axis=true,
    max space between ticks=25pt,    
    every axis/.style={  
        axis y line=left,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis line style={thick,->,>=latex, shorten >=-.4cm},
    },
    xtick=\empty,
    every axis plot/.append style={thick},
    tick style={black, thick},
}

\tikzset{
    semithick/.style={line width=1.2pt},
}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[% activate!
up to date check={simple}, % do not force remake every time!
]%


\begin{document}
    \input{figure1.tex} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \input{figure2.tex} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\end{document}
```

File `figure1.tex` in the same directory

```
%% file figure1.tex

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot3[
        patch,patch refines=3,
        shader=faceted interp,
        patch type=biquadratic] 
        table[z expr=x^2-y^2]
        {
            x  y
            -2 -2
            2  -2
            2  2
            -2 2
            0  -2
            2  0
            0  2
            -2 0
            0  0
        };
    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

File `figure2.tex` in the same directory

```
%% file figure2.tex

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={Grids with shader=faceted interp}]
        
        \addplot3[patch,patch type=biquadratic,
        shader=faceted interp,patch refines=3]
        coordinates {
            (0,0,1) (6,1,1.6) (5,5,1.3) (-1,5,0)
            (3,1,0) (6,3,0.4) (2,6,1.1) (0,3,0.9)
            (3,3.75,0.5)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It will produce this output

[image: c]

At the same time `main-figure0.pdf` and `main-figure1.pdf` will be generated, with a page size of `3.2x2.2in`.

[image: a]

A second (faster) run will output the messages

```
(figure1.tex
===== Image 'main-figure0' is up-to-date. ======
)
(figure2.tex
===== Image 'main-figure1' is up-to-date. ======
)
```